# Cannot open/copy files on an external USB NTFS drive because of an issue with permissions

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, permissions, external-hard-drive, ntfs

**Short story:**

I have an external USB HDD drive (NTFS) with some important files which I cannot open/copy any longer because of an issue with access rights.

I assigned all necessary access rights in Windows 10 (the owner is `Administrators`, `Everyone` has full access rights). However I still cannot open/copy the files.

**Longer story:**

The owner of these files says that she did not do anything special with them. A few days ago I copied these files from one USB HDD drive to another one. The files were copied without any problems on the file owner's laptop. It was a Windows 7 laptop, and unfortunately we do not have this laptop any longer.

I also tried to open/copy these files on a Linux machine with the same result: "Permission denied".

I'd like to understand what is wrong with these files and recover them.

Here are some screenshots from Windows 10:

[image]

[image]

And from Linux (Ubuntu/Nautilus):

[image]

**UPDATE:** The external HDD drive is brand new. I can move the files from on directory to another on the same drive. I just cannot copy (duplicate) and open them.

Comment: This sounds unfortuante, @Alexey! :( I'd recommend you try a couple of other methods to [Take Ownership of the external drive in Windows](https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2808-take-ownership-file-folder-drive-registry-key-windows-8-a.html) and also try to [Change access permissions through the CMD prompt](https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/2815-permissions-allow-deny-access-users-groups-windows-8-a.html). If that doesn't help either, please make sure you run the HDD's brand-specific diagnostic tool to determine the health and SMART status of the drive itself.Keep me posted & good luck!

Comment: Worst-case scenario, & to avoid any possible data-loss, if you know someone with a Mac, they can simply be set to ignore ownership on all except the boot volume, so you would be able to bypass perms that way.

Comment: @Tetsujin , shouldn't his Linux operating system ignore the NTFS permissions, also?

Comment: I really don't know nix well enough to say. On Mac it's a checkbox on the Get Info pane for the volume, idk where/if it would be in nix.

Comment: @Tetsujin, thanks, I'll consider trying it on a Mac.

Comment: Check the effective permissions. Check the permissions of the G:\ mount.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the answer to my question: these files are encrypted with Windows built-in (EFS) encryption. Here is a screenshot which, probably, proves it:

[image]

My understanding is that we will not be able to decrypt these files as we no longer have the laptop on which they were encrypted. Anyway, it's probably a subject for another question.